# App is crashing due to the SQLite error code:11

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios5.1

My application is keep crashing first or second time with the error "abc.sqlite is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is malformed', NSSQLiteErrorDomain=11"
I am unable to track it . anyone Plz help

thanks

Comment: Maybe abc.sqlite IS corrupted. How was it created or where did the file come from? How did you copy it to your application?

Comment: Phillippe is asking because you can check the error code on the [SQLite Result Codes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) page. Error 11 is `#define SQLITE_CORRUPT     11   /* The database disk image is malformed */`.

Comment: Recreate your database and try again.

Comment: I solve it my own .The app was crashing because it is loading on different thread and app start retrieving data before database install.

Comment: @nikhil If you solved it on your own, you should post your solution as a new answer and mark it as accepted answer

Comment: By "before database install", do you mean before adding persistent store @nikhil ?

Answer (score 2):

(Taken from one of the comments above)

The app was crashing because it was loading on a different thread, app tried to retrieve data before the database was even installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not entirely true, I ran into same issue today on my iphone, hookup to macbook and use xcode to bring db from iphone to macbook. I used SQLite DB browser, ran PRAGMA integrity_check, it shows an error on one of the pages with code 11. Luckily my table only has 10 records. Wierd thing was when I run "select * from tableA", only 3 records come back. I was able to fix the database accidentally by re-number of some record ID, when saving changes, those missing records shows up mysteriously.. while the corrupted record disappeared.

Answer (score -3):

I just got same code 11 on my xaiomi note 11 while trying to open whatsapp business and the fix is go to settings and select advance settings. Select processes and limit it to at least 2.

This will close all processes running on the background and limit it to just the app opened but nor more than two apps can run at a time. The problem was solved.